# Something like #warning directive for Java?

Tags: java, debugging, preprocessor

In my project I have something like `final boolean Debug.USE_DEBUG_MODE` and I'm then always forgetting to switch it back to `false`. 
I wonder if I can put something similar to the `#warning` C++ directive so I don't forget to change the code back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `//TODO Change this later` Task Tag in eclipse and configure Eclipse to display a compile-time warning for all `TODO`s.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //TODO Change this line before final build.
    String mode = "DEV"
}
```

You can see all such Task Tags collectively, in one place by doing `Window > Show View > Markers`.

Note that there are others too, like `FIXME`, `XXX`. By default the priority of a `TODO` tag is `NORMAL` and that of `FIXME` is a `HIGH`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I shall now figure out how to configure Eclipse to display a compile-time warning for all TODOs...

Comment: For IntelliJ IDEA you can place //TODO lines in the code, and display them with View - Tool Windows - TODO. That shows them in a tab at the bottom of the screen, but not as warnings in the Messages tab. Don't think that's possible.